# Nameserver locked on public access point

Tags: dns, vpn, resolv.conf

I can connect to a wifi hotspot that is free and only asks registration (this is the city's facility).

I got kicked from using it, because it detected my Tor usage. But thankfully, it was only temporary. Now I need to use Tor, and so I would like to access it through my VPN that I can connect to.

But the nameserver is locked to the access point, and my update-resolv-conf script is noneffective, meaning that I am connected to the VPN, but the `/etc/resolv.conf` file keeps the hotspot device as nameserver. How can I bypass that?
The OS is a x64 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, so it comes with systemd and resolvconf.

Comment: This is not a security problem but is about how to configure the name server in your system. You might have more luck at [superuser.se] but you should also add more information about the system since currently you not even specify what kind of OS you use (probably some kind of Linux, but even there different distributions behave differently).

Comment: Why can't you just edit `/etc/resolved.conf` in the meantime?

Comment: I edited the question to provide infos, Steffen.
Multithr3at3d: I did not think of that, but I tried to run update-resolv-conf manually with no effects, and actually writting to resolv.conf just works... thanks

Comment: I am thinking on to start a bounty on your question; however I do this only if you get here.

Comment: well if you think you are going to get some interesting answers go on lad.
however bounty hunters sometimes only go for the tokens, and you might be disapointed. The info you probably seek is "how do they do it" ? They must use the standard protocols (dhcp ?) to give you only their nameservers, since your network manager updates the resolv.conf file, this will only be so.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase the question so we can know if I understand the question correct.

*Is there a way to configure my computer to use a different nameserver (probably the one I want) than the one provided by my hotspot device ?*

Answer is **YES**.

`resolvconf` has special files to prepend when (re)generating the `resolv.conf`. And the file is in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`. Just tell resolvconf to use different nameserver by adding

> nameserver 1.1.1.1

to the file. And then run the following for generating a new `resolv.conf`

`$ sudo resolvconf -u`

Comment: Unless the network the OP connects to blocks outgoing connections to port 53....

Comment: OpenDNS can respond on Port 5353.

Comment: this might be the proper solution, instead of reediting the resolv.conf manualy each time you have established a wifi connection to the hotspot. I wouldn't be able to try it now though since I've moved.